# using henceforth in a paragraph to say that I will refer to X as Y from now on

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

> A said that X and Y are essential to Q.

If I want to refer to X and Y as Z only from now on, how do I use henceforth? Is this grammatically and structurally correct?

> A said that X and Y (henceforth I will refer to X and Y as Z) are essential on Q.

Example:

> Doctor Snoop said that food and water (henceforth I will refer to food and water as nutrition) are essential to survival.

Is there a shorter/better way of using henceforth in this context?

Comment: Those examples work, but you seem to be looking for a way to use henceforth. Can you not find some real cases?

Answer (score -2):

If you turn it around, you don't need to worry about *henceforth* or the additional wording:

> Doctor Snoop said that nutrition (food and water) is essential to survival.

It also avoids the awkwardness of initially using words you *don't* want to use going forward.